# Do I have to reinstall Mac OS in case something goes wrong during a Windows Boot Camp install?

Tags: macos, mac, boot-camp, reinstall, windows-installation

I have a Macbook laptop running Snow Leopard, there's absolutely no information on the laptop, just a few unimportant files on it, I wanted to use Boot Camp Assistant (version 3) to create a partition and install Windows on it to run Windows alongside Mac OS. My CD/DVD drive doesn't work at all so I'm gonna have to mount Windows on a USB stick and install it from there.

My question is, when I start Boot Camp it asks me to back up my files but I have nothing to back up, I was just wondering, in case I go through with the Windows install and something goes wrong do I have to reinstall Snow Leopard? My Snow Leopard install DVD can't be read by the laptop that's why I ask, I wouldn't know what to do if I had to reinstall it.

Comment: If you really have **nothing** to backup just skip that step.  In thoery something could go wrong that would force you to install a fresh OS X installation hence the warning to backup your files

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have a way to install a fresh OS X installation, as the OS X install DVD can't be read by my laptop, if I'm asked to reinstall Mac OS I can't do it.

Comment: You can make a flash drive installer.  If you are really worried create an image of the hdd.

Comment: Basically what I want to know is: Will I ever, for whatever reason, be asked during this Windoes Boot Camp installation to reinstall the Mac OS (in case something goes wrong)? I'm not worried about the HDD as I have like 5 unimportant PDF files on it and that's it. I can't create a flash drive installer as I only have one USB drive, which is gonna be used to mount the Windows installer.

Comment: Anything can happen if you are woried take steps to protect yourself from the worst case.  You can purchase a USB HUB, repurpose the drive, or any number of possible solutions if the worst case happens.

Comment: Good thing I have all my information on another laptop, I'm glad I have more clarity now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what goes wrong during the Windows installation. The biggest potential for damaging OS X during the install is if you don't do the reformat step right. When you run Boot Camp Assistant, it gives you the option to print a set of instructions; PRINT THEM, and then follow the instructions carefully.

The reason it's tricky is that you want your Windows installation on an NTFS-formatted volume, but OS X doesn't know how to create NTFS volumes. So Boot Camp Assistant creates a FAT32 volume instead, and then you're supposed to use the Windows installer to reformat it to NTFS format. If you get this step wrong, you could format the OS X volume by mistake, or reformat the entire disk (including the OS X volume), or break some of the tricky dual-format partition table trickery Boot Camp Assistant sets up, or...

So the worst case is that you might have to reinstall OS X, then rerun Boot Camp Assistant to reinstall Windows. Would a backup help speed things up in this situation? If not, don't worry about it. But the really important thing is to follow those instructions (especially the reformat steps) carefully.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, I don't know what I would have to back up as there were only 5 files on the laptop (other than the apps, folders and files the laptop starts with) which I just deleted, I couldn't care less about losing information as I don't have any on the laptop, I care about having to reinstall the Mac OS at some point, for some reason as I don't have a way to do it, thanks.

Comment: @RichJennings: Since your CD/DVD drive doesn't work, reinstalling OS X will probably be rather tricky... I'd be tempted to recommend a full *bootable* backup (made with something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com)), so you have a way to get at Disk Utility, reinstall (/recover) the OS, etc in case something does go wrong. A non-bootable backup (like Snow Leopard's Time Machine) probably won't be much use.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can make the DVD drive run a DVD Windows installer and take it from there, thank you.